# Serialize JSON String as JSON Object

Tags: json, string, kotlin, serialization

I am writing a custom Serializer for kotlin.serialization which interprets a JSON variable as a String no matter of its type. Deserializing works out fine. But I have trouble serializing the String into its original structure again.

At the moment I just deserialize the value as a String. But that adds extra quotes around the value and leads to problems.

Here is a quick example:

```kotlin
//
//Custom serializer:
//
object JsonToStringSerializer : KSerializer<String> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = PrimitiveDescriptor("JsonToStringSerializer", PrimitiveKind.STRING)

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: String) {
        if(value.startsWith("[") || value.startsWith("{")) {
            encoder.encodeString(value) //<-- bad solution
            println("Oh no! Object has been turned into a String!")
        }
        else //will also encode Int, Float, Boolean, ... into String - but that is ok
            encoder.encodeString(value)
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): String {
        val output = (decoder as JsonInput).decodeJson().toString()
        return if(output.startsWith("\""))
            output.substring(1, output.length-1)
        else output
    }
}

//
//Data structure for test:
//
@Serializable
class Test (
    @Serializable(with = JsonToStringSerializer::class) val objValue: String,
    val stringValue: String
)

//
//test logic:
//
fun test() {
    val jsonString = "{\"objValue\": [1,2], \"stringValue\": \"test\"}"
    val obj = Json(JsonConfiguration.Stable).parse(Test.serializer(), json)
    val newJsonString = Json(JsonConfiguration.Stable).stringify(Test.serializer(), obj)

    println(newJsonString)
    //expected result:  {"objValue": [1,2], "stringValue": "test"}
    //actual result:    {"objValue": "[1,2]", "stringValue": "test"}
}
```

After some digging I found that `encoder` in `serialize()` belongs to the class `StreamingJsonOutput`.
I can think of three possible solutions. But I ran into a wall with each of them:

1. If I had a way to directly `print()` to `composer` from `StreamingJsonOutput` I could add the String manually to the output. But unfortunately `composer` is private (and `StreamingJsonOutput` is internal as well).
2. Another way would be to use the configuration `unquotedPrint` which would create Strings without quotes. But then `stringValue` would not have quotes either. So I need a way to just change the configuration only temporariy.
3. I could also just deserialize the `value` String from `serialize()` into a real object and then just let the encoder serialize it correctly. The problem, apart from the performance overhead, is that I don't know which datastructure to expect in `value`. So I am not able to deserialize it.

I hope somebody has an idea how to deal with that.
Thank you very much! :)